# Move to root ViewController from popup view swift

Tags: swift, view, popup

I have seen the similar question but could't fine a suitable ans. i peresent a view now I want to move to root view controller from that view on button click.  `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` is not working.

also tried below code but its not working for me.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
(appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: are you sure self.navigationController it is not nil?

Comment: self.navigationController is nil.

Comment: that's not good, you have to read some articles or documentation on how to operate with NavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay here is the solution create a protocol which throws a delegate to whoever conform to it so that controller can know that the button is clicked, so your parent controller has the navigation controller which will pop you to root view controller

in your popvc.swift

```
    protocol PopupDelegate : AnyObject{
        func buttonTapped(_ status : Bool)
    }
    
    class popUpVc: UIViewController {
    
        weak var delegate : PopupDelegate?
    
     @IBAction func btnLoginAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
      self.delegate?.buttonTapped(true)
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
     }
    
    }
```

now in your parent view controller which is presenting the pop up

```
        let vc = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WaitingVc") as! WaitingVc
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

conform to the protocol like this

```
extension yourParentVC : PopupDelegate{

func PopupDelegate(_ status: Bool) {
if status{
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
   }

}
```

remember whenever you use

```
self.delegate?.buttonTapped(true)
```

the parentVc will pop you out so you can use delay or something or can call the line in completion of dismiss to not miss the animations.